# the menu items in menubar is not active and cannot be selected or clicked

Tags: java, gwt, web, smartgwt, menubar

I've got a problem. I'm writting a web application in the gwt. i wanna get a menubar this is my code:

```
Menu[] menus = new Menu[2];
        MenuBar plikMenu = new MenuBar();

        Menu menuPlik = new Menu();

        MenuItem itemZmianaHasla = new MenuItem("Zmiana hasła...");
        //MenuItem itemDodajUzytkownika = new MenuItem("Dodaj użytkownika...");
        MenuItem itemDodajUzytkownika = new MenuItem("Dodaj użytkownika...");

        itemDodajUzytkownika.addClickHandler(new com.smartgwt.client.widgets.menu.events.ClickHandler() {

            public void onClick(final MenuItemClickEvent event) {               

                DodajUzytkownika uzytkownik = new DodajUzytkownika();
                uzytkownik.center();
                uzytkownik.show();

            }
        });
        MenuItem itemUsunUzytkownika = new MenuItem("Usuń użytkownika");
        MenuItem itemDodajGrupe = new MenuItem("Dodaj grupę...");
        MenuItem itemZarzadzanieSesjami = new MenuItem("Zarządzanie sesjami");
        MenuItemSeparator separator = new MenuItemSeparator();

        MenuItem itemZarzadzanieLicencjami = new MenuItem("Zarządzanie licencjami");
        MenuItem itemRaporty = new MenuItem("Raporty");
        MenuItem itemBackupOracle = new MenuItem("Backup Oracle...");
        MenuItem itemPrzywracanieOracle = new MenuItem("Przywracanie Oracle...");
        MenuItem itemEksportLogiczny = new MenuItem("Eksport logiczny");
        MenuItem itemWyjscie = new MenuItem("Wyjście");
        menuPlik.setItems(itemZmianaHasla, itemDodajUzytkownika, itemUsunUzytkownika,itemDodajGrupe,itemZarzadzanieSesjami,separator, itemZarzadzanieLicencjami,itemRaporty,separator, itemBackupOracle,itemPrzywracanieOracle,itemEksportLogiczny,itemWyjscie);
        menuPlik.setTitle("Plik");
        menuPlik.setWidth(100);
        menus[0] = menuPlik;

        Menu menuPomoc = new Menu();
        menuPomoc.setShowShadow(true);
        menuPomoc.setShadowDepth(10);
        MenuItem itemLicencja = new MenuItem("Licencja...");
        MenuItem itemPodrecznikAdministratora = new MenuItem("Podręcznik administratora...");
        MenuItem itemOProgramie = new MenuItem("O programie...");
        menuPomoc.setItems(itemLicencja, itemPodrecznikAdministratora, itemOProgramie);
        menuPomoc.setTitle("Pomoc");
        menuPomoc.setWidth(80);
        menus[1] = menuPomoc;        
        plikMenu.addMenus(menus, 0);    
        plikMenu.setWidth(80);
        plikMenu.enable();


        dialogHTopPanel.addMember(plikMenu);
```

i use a smartgwt components. the menubar with items is visible, but if I wanna click one of them, nothing happend. even the item is not highlighted. 
Does anyone knows what I do wrong?

Thank you for any help

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the events that handle the click action of the menu.

For example if you want to add an action to one menu item you should do this as follows

```
MenuItem itemRaporty = new MenuItem("Raporty");
itemRaporty.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {

    public void onClick(final MenuItemClickEvent event) {
        //processClickEvent();
    }
});
```

Comment: i have tried to that. for example i've got that: MenuItem itemDodajUzytkownika = new MenuItem("Dodaj użytkownika...");

        itemDodajUzytkownika.addClickHandler(new com.smartgwt.client.widgets.menu.events.ClickHandler() {

            public void onClick(final MenuItemClickEvent event) {               

                DodajUzytkownika uzytkownik = new DodajUzytkownika();
                uzytkownik.center();
                uzytkownik.show();

            }
        }); But its not working, because I cannot click the item. Why I can't click item?

Comment: have you checked the return value of isEnabled() for the MenuItem?

Comment: If the isEnabled() is false try the setEnabled(true); method of the menu item object